# Process Data within Flask WTForms Submission

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I would like to reformat the data submitted via WTForms by utilizing the [process_data function](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.Field.process_data). I am able to successfully submit the form, however, the data is not modified in the output as expected. I've included a simplified example of my forms.py file below.

The goal of this form would be to input the value of "10,000" and return the string "10000".

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField

class SimpleForm(FlaskForm):
    price = StringField('price')

    def process_price(self, price):
        price.data = str(price).replace(',','')
```

Answer (score 1):

`process_data` is a method on the base `Field` class ([source](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/src/wtforms/fields/core.py#L338)). To use, you need to write a custom implementation of some Field class (`StringField`, in your instance) and override this method, then use this field in your form definition. For example:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField

class CustomStringField(StringField):

    def process_data(self, data):
        self.data = str(data).replace(',', '')    

class SimpleForm(FlaskForm):
    price = CustomStringField('price')
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same result without having to write a custom field class?